# Bootstrap wysiwyg issue while unchecking toolbar buttons

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, wysiwyg, contenteditable, rich-text-editor

Go to http://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/

type something like "hi there"

select the text and click on Bold, Italic and Strike

Now go to the end of string, give a space and uncheck Bold. Notice how it gets unchecked but Italic & strike is active [this is corect]

Now uncheck Italic and suddenly Bold becomes checked [This is the issue]

Comment: Have you emailed your question to MindMap?

Comment: I did... am trying to go through their issue list on git... Posted it here to see if someone encountered it and how they fixed it :/

Answer (score 1):

So this issue got fixed for me with this pull

https://github.com/mindmup/bootstrap-wysiwyg/pull/77